# template v-slot inside <v-data-table> is not working in vue 2.0.15

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i've tried to create a v-data-table including  so i can add another field with a button, but it seems that is not working.

Here is the code:
https://codepen.io/gerak/pen/yLBpqqG

The thing is when i change the package https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.14/vuetify.min.js with to a newest version like this one:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.0.15/vuetify.min.js the table ignore the  tag.

HTML

```
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td >{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td><v-btn>Created Button</v-btn></td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Button field', value: 'buttonField' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

I don't get any error, only the table stops appearing. Could it be a version problem?

Comment: I see errors in the console if I change your codepen to use 2.0.15 Did you change the css too? Not that it seems to matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slots are working differently, you've template per field, to add buttons in a table you can do it like this (https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/dybJgjL?editors=1010) :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
        <v-btn>Created Button</v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Actions', value: 'action', sortable: false }
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed. A nice, simple clean explanation. Thanks.!